# Changing color of application window (Mavericks)

Tags: macos, themes

Is there a way to hack just a single application to change the color of the window chrome itself, like the topmost bar where window title and min/maximize buttons are located?

Comment: No way. Only if you are developer of this app, or app already have custom non-default background.